# In LINQPad LinqToSql query with database context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linqpad

I aways copy LINQtoSql query from code to LINQPad for testing, but it have a little inconvenient of this.

My code:

[image]

But when I copy it to LINQPad for testing:

[image]

LINQPad can't recognizing the database context ***"db"***, so I have to remove ***"db"*** manually.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your query with the line

`var db = this;`